# SQL Selecting all objects from a table having similar date and ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL and am having trouble figuring out this query.  I have a database table which is used to store users' answers to a form that they fill out.

This table has:

```
AnswerID (Primary Key, bigint), 
Answer (varchar),
QuestionID (bigint), 
CompanyID (int), 
Date (smalldatetime).
```

I want to select all Answers which have the same CompanyID and Date.  This gives me enough information to determine *all* of a company's answers to *one* form (a single form can have more than one question and thus more than one answer).  However, we don't know/care what the date and CompanyID are, exactly, at the time of query -- we just want to total up each company's answers to the form (in a loop, and perform that for every company).

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ???
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio...

Comment: Which is not a DBMS but a SQL client application - but as it only supports SQL Server it also defines your DBMS ;)

Comment: Do you want the answers?  Or count?  Or what?  Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: "I want to select all Answers which have the same CompanyID and Date." That's unclear. Same as *what?*

Comment: Meaning all answers that have the same CompanyID and the same Date. (Not CompanyID = Date).

Answer (score 1):

Use this  query by Company and date

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
group by CompanyID,Date 
order by CompanyID,Date
```

if you want by Company,Date and question then

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
group by CompanyID,Date,QuestionID
order by CompanyID,Date
```

if you want to count all answers by Company and Date then

```
SELECT CompantID,Date,count(*)TotalAnswer FROM tablename 
group by CompanyID,Date,QuestionID
order by CompanyID,Date
```

Comment: I think this looks correct, this will give me everything at once but since it is in order then I can use programming logic to sort out the total for each company (loop and continue totaling up until CompanyID changes, then start total at 0 and continue again).

Comment: Yes you can do that, but what do you mean by total by company. Are you calculating any sum of result or sum of answers by company and date?.

Comment: Sum of answers by company and date. For example, if CompanyA answered 5, 13, 7 on date 5/13, then that total would be 25, then we total CompanyB, CompanyC, etc...

Answer (score 1):

for sql server, use this query to get the count of answer by company Id. 
@from and @to are variables to select time range for answer.

```
 select CompanyID, count(*) as NumberOfAnswer from tableName
 where Date >= @from and Date <=@to
 group by CompanyID
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you mention in a comment that you want a total of the answer values, then you might want to consider doing that as part of the query: RDBMSs are good at that sort of work and they can do it without looping (i.e. set-based). Only slight fly in the ointment is the answer being text - any aggregate (like `SUM`) that you use will fall over if there is an alpha answer (e.g. `a`) rather than one which is numeric. Expanding slightly on the answers already given by others gives you this:

```
SELECT CompanyID, [Date], SUM(CAST(Answer AS int)) AS Total
FROM test
GROUP BY CompanyID, Date
ORDER BY CompanyID, Date
```

[Working example on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/569c8/1)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't clearly get what you really need, but if you want all the info representing clearly in a list, sample code here:
`select * from tablename order by CompanyID,Date,QuestionID`